# Chart library that creates negative bar charts & ability to overlay second chart

Tags: php, javascript, charts, visualization

I know there are quite a few js & php chart libraries although I am not sure of the best method to create charts to look very similar to the image displayed below:

I am trying to create a chart that will allow me to use negative values - the tricky bit is the 'dark grey' overlay as I am not sure of the best library for doing this, I've used Google Charts but not had quite much success.

Any suggestions would be welcomed - thanks :)

[image: chart with negative values & secondary overlay values]

Comment: have you looked at the jplot charts?  There are many options available.  I have used it in the past and it is fairly simple to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this easily with amCharts.com:

1) take this chart as a base: http://amcharts.com/javascript/stacked-bar-chart/
2) create 2 serial charts (you can achieve quite the same with one chart too, but it might be a bit complicated to setup labels)
3) most important - set stackType of ValueAxis to "3d". this will make the bars to overlay as in your example.
4) set fillAlphas for the underlay graphs to <1 value so that they would be transparent.